# Creating an If/Else statement using WPAlchemy MetaBox radio boxs

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I am using the WPAlchemy MetaBox Class to create additional metaboxs on my site.  One has a section with a group of radio boxes.   I've coded it as follows:

```
    <?php $mb->the_field('docposs'); ?>
    <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="yes"<?php $mb->the_radio_state('yes')?' checked="checked"':''; ?>/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="no"<?php $mb->the_radio_state('no')?' checked="checked"':''; ?>/>No
    <input type="radio" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="unknown"<?php $mb->the_radio_state('unknown')?' checked="checked"':''; ?> />Unknown
```

What I would like to be able to do in my template is echo a string based on which box returns checked, something like:

```
if (checkbox == yes) {
    echo "If you wish to make";
} elseif (checkbox == no) {
    echo "an apple pie from scratch,";
} else {
    echo "you must first invent the universe";
}
```

But I cant make it work :(

This (and many ridiculous variations on this) just returns 'yes' instead of the echo.

```
if ($provenance_mb->the_value('docposs') == yes) {
 echo 'hello world';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are doing wrong, your code looks ok at first glance ... make sure you represent `yes` and `no` as string values ...

```
if ( 'yes' == $provenance_mb->get_the_value( 'docposs' ) ) {
    echo "If you wish to make";
} else if ( 'no' == $provenance_mb->get_the_value( 'docposs' ) ) {
    echo "an apple pie from scratch,";
} else {
    echo "you must first invent the universe";
}
```

Comment: Frustratingly, your code returns "yesyesyou must first invent the universe"

Almost as if the 'yes' == $provenance_mb->the_value( 'docposs' ) and the 'no' == $provenance_mb->the_value( 'docposs' ) are calling it.

Comment: Ah!  I got it.  There was an seperate function for returning the value called 'get_the_value' (which I swore I tried).  the_value would only print it out.

Thank you for the push in the right direction! (it seems like after hours of hitting a wall, as soon as I give in and ask a question I figure it out, and it is easy)